# PHP - namespaces and autoloading issues

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload

I've set up a simple autoload to understand the principles when working together with namespaces.

**test.php:**

```
namespace House;

function __autoload($classname) 
{
    $parts = explode('\\', $classname);

    $class = 'Room/'.end($parts).'.php';

    require_once($class);
}


$Toy = new Toy();
echo $Toy->hello();
```

**Room/Toy.php:**

```
namespace House;

class Toy 
{
    public function hello() { return "HELLO"; }
}
```

When declaring $Toy I get *Fatal error: Class 'House\Toy' not found in test.php on line 18*

What have I dont wrong here?

When removing __autoload function and instead just putting in

```
require_once('Room/Toy.php');
```

It works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `test.php` should look like this:

```
use House\Toy as Toy;

function __autoload($classname) 
{
    $parts = explode('\\', $classname);
    $class = 'Room/'.end($parts).'.php'; 
    require_once($class);
}

$Toy = new Toy();
echo $Toy->hello();
```

If you are putting `namespace House` on the top of the file, all functions declared in that file will belong to the namespace `House`. Meaning `__autoload()` get's `House\__autoload()` and will loose it's *magic* meaning.

Another thing, wouldn't it be better to store the files of the namespace `House` in a folder named `House`? (You are currently using `Room`). If you are doing so, the `__autoload()` function could be written more generally:

```
function __autoload($classname)
{
    $parts = explode('\\', $classname);
    $path = implode('/', $parts) . '.php';
    require_once($path);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that __autoload is not called at all if namespace is declared before it? I know the structure is bad, this is me experimenting to understand namespaces really.

Comment: Yes, I meant that. It is not called since it is not implemented. You only implemented `House\__autoload()` but PHP will call `\__autoload()` meaning the `__autoload()` defined in the global namespace. However you are free to use any function from any namespace (and/or class) you wish, using `spl_autoload_register()`.

Comment: Ok now I get it. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this autoloader instead :) and add the absolute path to directory Room to your include path. Inside Room have another directory called House where Toy.php will be located.

```
<?php

spl_autoload_register ( function ( $className, $fileExtensions = null ) {
    $className = str_replace ( '_', '/', $className );
    $className = str_replace ( '\\', '/', $className );
    $file = stream_resolve_include_path ( $className . '.php' );
    if ( $file !== false ) {
        include $file;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```